# How to create global command like echo in Python, and make to install via pip?

Tags: python, pip

Can I make following terminal log possible?

```
$ pip install pyecho
$ pyecho 'Lorem ipsum'
Lorem ipsum
```

In the above, *pyecho* is virtual program which registered with PyPI and be made for printing a sentence like *echo*.

How to create *pyecho*, a global command written in Python?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It only takes three simple steps to make you python app pip-installable.

1. Write your script or application
2. Add a setup script
3. Upload to PyPI

After this, you and anyone else can install it by typing:
`pip install my_awesome_pyecho`

## Write your script

The script can really simple or big and advanced. We'll cover the most basic example

```
import sys

for arg in sys.argv:
   print arg
```

You can name the script anything, but this name will be the name you'll be typing every time, so make sure it's not to difficult. We'll name our script pyecho.

## Add a setup script

The setup.py file is is the centre of building, distributing and installing modules using the Distutils.

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(
    name='my-awesome-pyecho',    # This is the name of your PyPI-package.
     version='0.1',                          # Update the version number for new releases
     scripts=['pyecho']                  # The name of your scipt, and also the command you'll be using for calling it
)
```

**Optional**: We can now package the script using python setup.py sdist. This will create a dist folder containing all your distributions. After unpacking the distribution file, you can simply install it using sudo python setup.py install.

## Upload to PyPI

First, you need to register the package on PyPi. This is simply done by typing python setup.py register. If you haven't registered a package from this computer before, you'll be prompted with this message:

```
$ python setup.py register
running register
We need to know who you are, so please choose either:
1. use your existing login,
2. register as a new user,
3. have the server generate a new password for you (and email it to you), or
4. quit
Your selection [default 1]:
...
```

Once this is done, register will ask you if you want to save your login information in the .pypirc file. By default, this will store the login name and the password. The next step is to upload your package. Just type python setup.py sdist upload, and the package is now available on PyPI! You can save a few keystrokes by doing it all in one command: python setup.py register sdist upload.

[Source](http://marthall.github.io/blog/how-to-package-a-python-app/)

Comment: With your kindness, I've noticed that one of the important things is the `scripts` argument in `setuptools.setup`; its element used to determine not only command name, but relative path of a specified script. Thank you!